# Options and Resources for AzureAD with Vue3 and .NET6

Tags: vue.js, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, msal

I am trying to figure out and implement a solution for using AzureAD with a Vue3/Net6 App (and probably Vue2). I have tried investigating this documentation mostly for [msal-browser](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser), but I will be honest, its verbose and difficult to understand what is required and what isn't.

My question is: Is MSAL the simplest course here? Should I persue a setup purely from a backend perspective with one of Microsofts .Net packages? Other options or recommendations would be great! :)

Comment: I could only say, microsoft provides [AAD samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#single-page-applications) here, but not including a sample for Vue. But according to the samples, we can say MSAL library can be used in SPA for user sign in an get access token for calling backend api.

Comment: I suggest you searching for `vue integrate aad` and see if there's a blog where provides a sample

Answer (score 0):

It certainly would not be the simplest solution. If you want simple, use Microsoft.Identity.Web: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web

Use this on the backend to log the user in and obtain the needed tokens. For the Vue frontend just rely on the cookie auth provided.

Using MSAL or OAuth/OIDC directly in the frontend application is unsafe, no matter if you use PKCE or not.